How to Dynamically Extract JSON Keys and Automate Flattened Table Generation in Dataform?
I’m getting started with Dataform and working on a project where I need to transform a source table containing a JSON column into a flattened and aggregated table.
My goal:
First of all, i would like to extract the top-level keys from the JSON column in the source table.
Then, dynamically turn these keys into columns in a new table.
And to conclude, extract the corresponding values for these keys and structure the result as a table where:

Columns: Represent the top-level keys from the JSON.
Rows: Contain the corresponding values for each record.

At the moment, what I've done so far :
A SQL query to extract all unique keys from the source table using JSON_KEYS():
function get_keys(table_alias) {
    return `WITH key_extraction AS (
              SELECT DISTINCT
                key 
              FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                  JSON_KEYS(event_data, 1) AS all_keys
                FROM
                  ${table_alias}
              ), UNNEST(all_keys) as key  
            )
           SELECT key as keys_array
            FROM key_extraction`;
}

This query retrieves a list of top-level keys from the JSON column.
-> I would like to use the output of this query inside my next function that dynamicaly generate parameters to build my flattened table.
The JavaScript function to dynamically generate a SQL query based on the extracted keys :
function generate_aggregated_queries(all_keys, table_alias) {
    const keys = all_keys;
    if (!Array.isArray(keys)) {
      throw new Error('Keys must be an array :', toString(keys));
    }
    const queries = keys.map((key) => {
        return `JSON_EXTRACT(event_data, '$.${key}') AS ${key.replace('-', '_')}`;
    });
    return `SELECT ${queries} FROM ${table_alias}`;
}

When I manually pass a static array of keys (for example ['items', 'value']) to this function in a new file like definitions/bronze_layer/json_keys.sqlx :
config {
  type: "operations",
  hasOutput: true,
  schema: "bronze_layer",
  name: "json_keys_staging"
}

${helpers.generate_aggregated_queries(['items', 'value'],ref("source_table"))}

I get this example output :



row
items
value




1
[{item_id: "1234", item_name: "test", price: 10}, {item_id: "1234", item_name: "test", price: 10}]
20


2
[{item_id: "1234", item_name: "test", price: 10}, {item_id: "1234", item_name: "test", price: 10}]
20



it works perfectly. The generated query produces a table with columns named after the keys, containing the corresponding values. But used keys in this example do not match all the keys retrieved in the get_keys() method because I wanna dynamise the ingestion of the keys.
I want to automate this process by dynamically passing the array of keys extracted from the get_keys() query into my JavaScript function. However, I’m stuck on how to use the output of the get_keys() query as an input for the generate_aggregated_queries() function.
Do you have any suggestions or ideas to help me solve this ?
Thank you in advance for your help! 
